# How to preserve airplane mode in Ubuntu 18.04 lts

Tags: 18.04, airplane-mode

I used to have ubuntu 16.04 lts . Now I have 18.04 lts . In 16.04 when I disabled wifi  , that option was preserved after shutdown and boot . Now in 18.04 lts if I disable wifi the option is not preserved . Hence the problem is not due to my G505s lenovo laptop . I know that airplane mode disables more than just wifi and I prefer that mode for personal reasons . I have searched in the internet and have not find anything helpful . 
**I would like to know how to preserve airplane mode in 18.04 lts .**

Comment: An off topic solution for me was just going to bios of my lenovo g505s laptop and disabling wireless . Like that the airplane mode is preserved ( since  the laptop does not have bluetooth ) .

Comment: It turns out , that now , the airplane mode is preserved after shutdown and boot . Maybe they did an update that fixed that .

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/hp-keycodes.service
```

Paste the following lines or type them into the file:

```
[Unit]
Description=HP setkeycodes fix

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Restart=no
RemainAfterExit=no
ExecStart=/usr/bin/setkeycodes e057 240 e058 240

[Install]
WantedBy=rescue.target
WantedBy=multi-user.target
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Save and confirm the filename with ctrl-x, y.

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl enable hp-keycodes.service
$ sudo reboot
```

Details can be found here [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965595/why-does-airplane-mode-keep-toggling-on-my-hp-laptop-in-ubuntu-18-04/965596#965596)