# airplane mode is switching on off continuously (18.04)

Tags: wireless, rfkill

I have updated ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04.
The system has worked properly for one day.

After that it started to switching between airplane ✈️ mode on and off continuously.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/hp-keycodes.service
```

Paste the following lines or type them into the file:

```
[Unit]
Description=HP setkeycodes fix

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Restart=no
RemainAfterExit=no
ExecStart=/usr/bin/setkeycodes e057 240 e058 240

[Install]
WantedBy=rescue.target
WantedBy=multi-user.target
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Save and confirm the filename with ctrl-x, y.

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl enable hp-keycodes.service
$ sudo reboot
```

Details can be found here [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965595/why-does-airplane-mode-keep-toggling-on-my-hp-laptop-in-ubuntu-18-04/965596#965596)