# Issues with new Intel wireless card

Tags: networking, wireless, suspend, hp, intel-wireless

I'm new here, this is my first question. Thanks all who are going to help me. I have Ubuntu 18.04 in dual boot with Windows 10.

This is the problem: I've recently changed my HP Pavilion G6 laptop wireless card (`Ralink RT 5390`) with an `Intel (R) 7620 ac` dual band wireless card.
The new wireless card worked properly on Windows, but it was "Hard-Blocked" on Ubuntu.

I tried everything, every rfkill unblock method, every modprobe thing too, but the laptop still remained in Aeroplane Mode, and I could read "use hardware switch to turn off". Obviously the keyboard key for Aeroplane Mode did absolutely nothing (neither with <kbd>fn</kbd> pressed nor without).

After doing all of that, I simply suspended the laptop (by closing the front lid), and reopening it WiFi magically worked. Each time I reboot the laptop I have to do this to make the WiFi work properly. Anyone knows how to resolve it?

Comment: Start here https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

Comment: This might have a relation to your problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/965595/why-does-airplane-mode-keep-toggling-on-my-hp-laptop-in-ubuntu-18-04/965596#965596 it is nearly the reverse of your problem, and it used to happen on my HP laptop, but the accepted answer there fixed it for me.