# Airplane mode turns on when laptop lid is closed

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows-10, wifi-hardware-switch, airplane-mode

I've read about two dozen various other similar issues, and none of those solutions have worked for me.

I'm running a dual boot of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 on an HP Pavillion, and whenever I'm running Ubuntu and I close the lid, airplane mode turns on (hard on, not soft on). I can turn it off by restarting my laptop, but that isn't practical to do every time.

I've tried F1-F12, and FN+F1-F12, and those don't turn airplane mode off. When I run `sudo rfkill list all` I get:

```
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Running `sudo rfkill unblock all` doesn't change anything.

EDIT: I've already tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965595/why-does-airplane-mode-keep-toggling-on-my-hp-laptop-in-ubuntu-18-04), and it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "Airplane Mode" keep toggling on my HP laptop in Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965595/why-does-airplane-mode-keep-toggling-on-my-hp-laptop-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: Already tried that.

Comment: are you trying to run the laptop after you closed its lid ?  not a good idea due to overheading risk

Comment: Nope. I'll use it, then need to close it to move it, use the bathroom, walk away, etc, then come back and open it back up, and it will be in airplane mode.

Comment: I see the same issue, and have not found a way to disable this.