# Wi-Fi is not working on HP Ralink RT3290LE (After sleep/suspend)

Tags: drivers, wireless, hp

EDIT: I now realise that all these happened after my laptop got into suspend/sleep. Sorry that I didnt realise this beforehand. Any solution now?

My wireless connection was working fine. But after a recent update, its not working. Airplane mode is persistently on. I am using dual boot with windows and wifi works fine over there. I tried many fixes that were previously posted but couldnt find a solution. i am now on ubuntu 18.04.3. Rfkill list shows hard block yes.
wifi settings shows "No Wifi adapter found
Laptop - Hp pavilion g6 2313AX

```
madhan@madhan-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
Kernel modules: rt2800pci, wl
```

rfkill list

```
madhan@madhan-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
```

Comment: This is not Realtek. It is Ralink.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Hardblock means that some hardware switch is off. Check it, or check BIOS settings too.

Comment: Thank you Pilot6. But there is no separate hardware switch. Fn+F12 or simply F12 doesnt respond. Its always red light- airplane mode on

Comment: Check BIOS. Maybe reset it to default. And please add the laptop model to the question. It is model specific.

Comment: Was it the full output of `rfkill list`?

Comment: yes... Thats the full output of rfkill list

Comment: Try to run `sudo modprobe hp-wmi`. Does it work?

Comment: yea I tried it. It doesnt help. I tried it once again now too. doesnt work

Comment: Did you try to reset bios?

Comment: Yes I reset BIOS to default. But still airplane mode persistently on. Wifi adapter not found. Thanks.

Comment: I have no more ideas. You need to get rid of that hardware block somehow.

Comment: Yes. i wish I could get rid of that. Thanks!

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146342/rfkill-shows-wifi-is-hard-blocked-but-there-is-no-way-to-unlock-it/1146349#1146349

Comment: Thank you chili555. But I have already tried that solution as per the answer. But the problem still exists. I understand that the issue has not much solutions. The closest that I came to solving this is by following https://webwiks.com/techcorner/get-ralink-rt3290-bluetooth-work-in-linux/    After doing as mentioned, the amber light Wifi goes off and blue light comes up- airplane mode goes off but still unable to connect to wifi. But when I reboot everything goes off and amber light returns again- airplane mode on

Comment: Makes me wonder why and how WiFi was working fine a week ago

Comment: EDIT: I now realise that all these happened after my laptop got into suspend/sleep. Sorry that I didnt realise this beforehand. Any solution now?