# HP Pavilion DV4 Ubuntu 18.04 airplane mode enabled WIFI and Bluetooth not working

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, bluetooth, hp

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 in my HP Pavilion DV4 laptop. After installing it shows that airplane mode is on by hardware switch

[image]

and there is no airplane mode disable switch I found in network

[image]

as a result WIFI and Bluetooth not working

[image]

[image]

When running `rfkill list all`

[image]

Also when I run on widows and press F12 airplane mode is on and off but in Ubuntu it doesn't work

[image]

> **`So how can I disable airplane, enable WIFI and Bluetooth`**

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with HP Pavilion 15-n208tx laptop. It has been 3 years since I am looking for a solution to this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/965595/267752

Comment: @THelper thanks I did try that before but didn't work see my comment there https://askubuntu.com/questions/965595/why-does-airplane-mode-keep-toggling-on-my-hp-laptop-in-ubuntu-18-04#comment1904227_965596

Answer (score 1):

After a long read and research, I discovered the issue is with `acpi=off` as a kernel boot parameter.

1. Edit your kernel boot parameter with:

`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

2. Look for the line with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite splash acpi=off"`
   <--parameters may defer based on your system - ->

Within the `" "` (quotes), replace `acpi=off` or any other `acpi` parameters with `acpi_osi=!`.

e.g.:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite splash acpi_osi=!"`

3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to Save and Confirm Change

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to return to terminal

4. Update grub with :

`sudo update-grub`

5. Reboot your machine.

Everything should be working fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

My wifi does not work after installing Ubuntu on an HP Pavilion DV-4 Laptop, I found that the touch switch that used to turn wifi off and on now toggles it into and out of airplane mode, I think that is the manual switch the system is referencing. At least it was for me.