# Wifi does not work after coming out of Suspend mode in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: network-manager, suspend, 20.04, wifi-hardware-switch, airplane-mode

Automatic **Suspend** happens once I close the my laptop lid or it is idle for a certain time. In suspend mode, Screen and other parts of the computer switch off to save power [more info here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-suspend.html.en).

> When I resume my session, Airplane mode is still on and I am not able to set it to off. It says turn off using the hardware switch, but my button doesn't respond.

**This only happens after system goes into Suspend mode and comes out of it. All other times my Airplane switch key on my HP Laptop works fine and i can set it on/off.**

[Here is detailed info of my system](https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c04700593). I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 in one of the partition.

### Question

How do I fix this Suspend mode ?

PS: It is pain in the ass to restart system every time it goes into suspend mode.

Answer (score 0):

Airplane Mode turning on automatically after suspend is a common problem with many HP laptops running Gnome. This is a fix for the same: (Source: [@Nicholas Stommel](https://askubuntu.com/users/488604/nicholas-stommel)'s [answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/965596/1099220))

Create and open this file in an editor

```
$ sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/hp-keycodes.service
```

Paste the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=HP setkeycodes fix

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Restart=no
RemainAfterExit=no
ExecStart=/usr/bin/setkeycodes e057 240 e058 240

[Install]
WantedBy=rescue.target
WantedBy=multi-user.target
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Save and close with ctrl+s, ctrl+x

Enable the script and reboot

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl enable hp-keycodes.service
$ sudo reboot
```

If you wish to stop your laptop from suspending at all, turn off Automatic Suspend under Power in Settings.

Comment: This is not working as still airplane mode is on after suspend mode. I saw that  **service is enabled** as `systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled` is showing _hp-keycodes.service                            enabled         enabled _. 'systemctl | grep running' shows it **not running**.