# HP Laptop Keyboard Layout

Tags: keyboard, hp

I have a hp 15-dp0321ng with a German Keyboard Layout recently switched from Windows to Ubuntu 20.4.2 on it. When I close the lid, it does not turn off or hibernate.

The screen turns off, but the fans keeps spinning. I don't have to re login after opening the lid again.

When I open it, it switches to Flightmode or back.

The Planemode-key (f12) doesn't do anything. The Brigthness keys (F2 and F3) are showing no reaction. On boot, the brightness is at minimum, which is also very annoying.

In my understanding, closing the laptop is also triggering a specific Key event.

Linux is just interpreting it wrong. Sadly I tried all the Hewlett Packard branded keyboard configurations, without success.

I as a noob didn't find a way to create or change a custom Layout. A way to do this, and identify the Keycodes would be ideal.

Thanks for your Help

PS: i found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965595/why-does-airplane-mode-keep-toggling-on-my-hp-laptop-in-ubuntu-18-04) related question, but its solutions also only circumvent the problem

Comment: Is the problem about keyboard layout or sleep?  Better separate questions.  No sleep when closing is a Linux feature that can be configured.

Comment: In 20.10 keyboard layout is in Settings > Language and Region > Input Sources.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?