# Airplane mode not disabling on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, uefi, wifi-hardware-switch, airplane-mode

**Problem:**
Laptop : HP 15 r074 tu
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS with Windows 10 dual boot.

In Ubuntu not able to turn off Airplane Mode, it says "Use hardware switch to turn off" but my laptop don't have hardware switch, I use F12 key to toggle the airplane mode.

**When problem started:**

I had Ubuntu 18.04 installed dual booted with Windows 7, at that time my WiFi was working perfectly fine.

I was able to toggle airplane mode using F12 key in both Ubuntu and Windows.

Now I have formatted the whole disk and converted it into gpt from mbr and installed windows 10 in UEFI mode.

After that I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 (UEFI), now Ubuntu starts with airplane mode on, I am not able to disable/toggle the airplane mode in Ubuntu.

In windows 10 it is working perfectly fine. There I am able to switch airplane mode.

**What I have tried:**

I have tried booting up with Ubuntu using USB live media, there also airplane mode is on by default, not able to turn it off.

I have also disabled fast boot / secure boot.

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
rfkill list all
```

which outputs

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
```

I have tried many commands from internet but nothing seems to be working.

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: F12 is your hardware switch. What are all the commands you have tried from the internet and what errors or messages have they given you? If no one knows what you have already tried you may just get told things you have tried already.

Comment: I don't remember the commands I have tried till. Since I have tried those commands 2 3 months ago, nothing worked hence continued using windows 10. But now I need to use Ubuntu only hence posted here for solutions.

Comment: Please show `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.rfkill active`

Comment: `aviation@aviatrix:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.rfkill active`
outputs `true`

Comment: Not sure if it is working nowadays. `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.rfkill active false`  relog your user in.

Comment: Tried setting to false and logged in again. Didn't worked.

Comment: Please take a look here https://askubuntu.com/questions/965595/why-does-airplane-mode-keep-toggling-on-my-hp-laptop-in-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Tried out steps in @nobody comment https://askubuntu.com/questions/965595/why-does-airplane-mode-keep-toggling-on-my-hp-laptop-in-ubuntu-18-04
Did not solve the issue.