# Airplane mode toggling when switching to tablet mode (HP spectre x360)

Tags: gnome, 22.04, hp, 22.10, airplane-mode

On Ubuntu 22.10 (hence kernel 5.19, gnome 43.1)

HP Spectre x360 2-in-1 16-f1xxx, i7-12700H, Iris XE (ADL GT2)

When switching between laptop and tablet mode, the airplane mode automatically toggles.

Expected behaviour: No link between tablet mode and airplane mode.

This can be seen as an update on the old
[Why does "Airplane Mode" keep toggling on my HP laptop in Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965595/why-does-airplane-mode-keep-toggling-on-my-hp-laptop-in-ubuntu-18-04?newreg=a44df08e83ae4e78a41e25679b0977ff)

The systemd solution described within was tried, and did not work. Notice that somebody commented that this fix does not work anymore (for him) on 22.04 .

I explored a little, and noticed that when using `sudo showkey -s`, no event registers. However, with `sudo showkey -k`, we get

> keycode 247 press
> keycode 247 release

So showkey does not get the  scancode, but only the keycode.

Apparently keycode 247 is KEY_RFKILL, which is indeed airplane mode.

Further, the culprit seems to be "Intel HID events". With `evtest` I get:

```
$ sudo evtest /dev/input/event17
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x19 vendor 0x0 product 0x0 version 0x0
Input device name: "Intel HID events"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 69 (KEY_NUMLOCK)
    Event code 102 (KEY_HOME)
    Event code 104 (KEY_PAGEUP)
    Event code 107 (KEY_END)
    Event code 109 (KEY_PAGEDOWN)
    Event code 113 (KEY_MUTE)
    Event code 114 (KEY_VOLUMEDOWN)
    Event code 115 (KEY_VOLUMEUP)
    Event code 116 (KEY_POWER)
    Event code 142 (KEY_SLEEP)
    Event code 164 (KEY_PLAYPAUSE)
    Event code 166 (KEY_STOPCD)
    Event code 224 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN)
    Event code 225 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSUP)
    Event code 240 (KEY_UNKNOWN)
    Event code 247 (KEY_RFKILL)
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1671615870.717544, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 08
Event: time 1671615870.717544, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 247 (KEY_RFKILL), value 1
Event: time 1671615870.717544, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1671615870.717556, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 247 (KEY_RFKILL), value 0
Event: time 1671615870.717556, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1671615871.877965, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 08
Event: time 1671615871.877965, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 247 (KEY_RFKILL), value 1
Event: time 1671615871.877965, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1671615871.877980, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 247 (KEY_RFKILL), value 0
Event: time 1671615871.877980, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1671615876.441854, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 08
Event: time 1671615876.441854, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 247 (KEY_RFKILL), value 1
Event: time 1671615876.441854, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1671615876.441866, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 247 (KEY_RFKILL), value 0
Event: time 1671615876.441866, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

Does that mean the ``bad'' scancode is 08? How can I ensure it does not trigger again?

Answer (score 2):

OK, with further work, I could set up a solution, inspired by
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes

I created a file /etc/udev/hwdb.d/91-solve-airplane.hwdb

```
# Spectre x360 16 2022 (Prevents Random airplane mode)
evdev:name:Intel HID events:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svnHP*:pn*HP[sS][pP][eE][cC][tT][rR][eE]*x3602-in-1*:*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_08=unknown
```

The end of the long line starting with evdev:name:Intel HID events must match /sys/class/dmi/id/modalias . The start was the device responsible. The keyboard key number 08 is the bad scancode.

After that

```
 sudo systemd-hwdb update
 sudo udevadm trigger
```

should work for the session. To have it permanent, use

```
sudo systemctl edit --full systemd-hwdb-update.service
```

and comment out the line

```
ConditionNeedsUpdate=/etc
```

Save to /etc/systemd/system/systemd-hwdb-update.service

You should be done.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! The steps to make it permanent was unnecessary for me.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: This solution is obsolete, I found a better solution that addresses the root of the issue. There is a bug in Intel's HID driver, to fix, follow the instructions at https://askubuntu.com/a/1483259/1688756

I found a solution that works on any desktop with any distro, and doesn't require you to make a kernel module or anything complicated like that.

https://askubuntu.com/a/1463613/1688756

In short, you download and set up a program called Hawck, rebind keycode 255 (the rfkill key, which is what triggers when the lid switch activated) to a null character, set Hawck to run on boot, and the problem is solved. Cheers!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and managed to fix it using your method. However, I needed a different device specification in the .hwdb file. To find out which one exactly, I refer to https://yulistic.gitlab.io/2017/12/linux-keymapping-with-udev-hwdb/.

Furthermore, I did not have to make the changes permanent. After reboot, the issue is still fixed. Time will tell if updates unfix anything.

See https://askubuntu.com/a/1468311/1696813 for my answer and more details.

Cheers jk